# I've created a series of buttons programmatically. How can I recognize them when clicked?

Tags: ios, swift, button

I have a method which generates several buttons, all with the same properties. The buttons are arranged vertically, like that:

[image]

What I need is that when each of them is clicked, it is capable of recognizing if it is the first one from the top, or the second one etc., printing "I'am the first/second/etc one".

How can I do it considering that the method they have is the same?

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is an integer, use the `tag` property in UIView.

Comment: This is the simplest and most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of buttons…

```
var buttons: [UIButton]
```

you could sort them by their position in their superview to determine their order:

```
var sortedButtons: [UIButton] {
    return buttons.sorted(by: { $0.frame.origin.y < $1.frame.origin.y })
}
```

and then get the index of a button (and vice-versa):

```
func index(of button: UIButton) -> Int {
    return sortedButtons.index(of: button)
}

func button(at index: Int) -> UIButton? {
    guard index < buttons.count else { return nil }
    return sortedButtons[index]
}
```

Then…

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let index = index(of: sender) else { return }
    sender.setTitle("I am \(index)", for: .normal)
}
```

This would also work if you added your buttons to an **Outlet Collection** in a storyboard:

```
@IBoutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty approach:

When dragging the outlet for the button, for the connection type select "Outlet Collection". This will create an outlet "to" a button array. Then you can drag and drop the rest of your buttons to this array. The order you make the drag n drop will be the order of your buttons in the array.
Then you can easily access them by index.
[image]

Caution: Easily breakable if re-drag n dropping the collection.